# Javascript, this pointer returns different values on browser and console

Tags: javascript, this

I am kinda new to JavaScript, so was just learning about "this" pointer, I tried to use the apply() to change the context of an object, I ran the code in NodeJS REPL, and the output was undefined and undefined.

```
    var word="Hello";
    var obj={word:"GB"};
    function foo(){return this.word;}
    console.log(foo());
    foo.apply(obj);
    console.log(foo());
```

And I ran the same in chrome browser, It output Hello and Hello, using apply(), the output was supposed to be Hello and GB.

[image]

I am confused about this usage.
Please help.

Comment: Doesn't matter how many times you execute `foo()` (including via `foo.apply(obj)`), you never change the value of `this.word` so why should it return anything different?

Comment: this.obj.word will give you what you desire!

Comment: I think your confusion comes from a misunderstanding about [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply). I suggest you read the documentation carefully and try `console.log(foo.apply(obj))`

Comment: To learn more about how the `this` keyworkd works in js, read https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md by kyle simpson.

Answer (score 1):

`console.log` the value after you call function using `Function.apply` as you are providing `this` context while invoking the function using `.apply(CONTEXT)`.

> `foo.apply(obj);` will not save the `this` context for the later `invokation` of `foo`

```js
var word = "Hello";
var obj = {
  word: "GB"
};

function foo() {
  return this.word;
}
console.log(foo());
console.log(foo.apply(obj));
```

You can use `.bind` and keep the reference in a variable so that referred function will always have the `binded-context`

```js
var word = "Hello";
var obj = {
  word: "GB"
};

function foo() {
  return this.word;
}
console.log(foo());
var bar = foo.bind(obj);
console.log(bar());
```

Comment: I did not know that apply does not save the context. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

`foo.apply(obj)` indeed returns "GB", but you are passing `foo()` to `console.log`

perhaps you have mistaken `apply` with `bind`?

```
console.log(foo()); // World
foo = foo.bind(obj);
console.log(foo()); // GB
```

or your way:

```
console.log(foo.apply(obj)); // GB
```

Comment: Yes, I wanted it work the way bind words, thanks :)